# Open On-Screen Keyboard when text input needed

Tags: c#, wpf, on-screen-keyboard

I need to open On-Screen Keyboard everytime when user click in control, that allows to input any text in it. Is any ideas about how to do that?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. then we will be able to correct your mistake.  :)

Comment: @shrot, it's difficult to make a mistake when you even don't know how to start. So now I need in advice about where should I look for.

Comment: what kind of application are you working on ? You need to provide some additional info like  its web based application on winform application ? Anyway start reading about event. Then you will be able to trigger an action based on event.

Comment: @shrot, I work at WPF app. I got many text fields such as textboxes and grid text fields. And now I need this app to work with touchScreen devices. So I can add MouseDown or smth like that events handlers for each text field, but I trying to find universal way to do this. And I hope that there is an WinAPI or maybe WPF Window events raising when user click (touch) text field. But I cant find it by myself so asced there.

Answer (score 2):

So assuming when input is needed, the user clicks on a button to launch the on screen keyboard... Then the code would be,

```
    string progFiles = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink";
    string onScreenKeyboardPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(progFiles, "TabTip.exe");
    onScreenKeyboardProc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(onScreenKeyboardPath);
```

You need to add

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Hope this helps :P

Comment: Thanks for helping but problem is not in opening a keyboard, it's in understanding when to do this. There is no button, only textboxes and grid fields.

Comment: @Denise Here OP asked how to trigger a event when focus is set to text box.